# remote javascript-ajax-php attack

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Javascript is a client-side language, so scripts can be read and copied.

Now consider this example.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#user').blur(function () {
            var dataString = 'user=' + user;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insertUser.php",
                data: dataString
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <label for='user' >User:</label>
    <input id="user"  type="text" />
</body>
```

**insertUser.php** :

```
<?php
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user');
if (isset($user)) {
    require_once("class.Database.php");
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (User) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Could someone write a script in his localhost for inserting his own data using the path to insertUser.php? Anyway to solve this?

Comment: Any code that inserts user supplied data should be authenticated, else a malicious person can fill up your database with junk in a few minutes

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Any script that receives input from the web - not just AJAX - *must* treat that data as if could potentially contain malicious data or be used in a malicious way. Sanitise and check everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Could someone write a script in his localhost for inserting his own data using the path to insertUser.php?**

Yes, anyone can post its own data using the path to insertUser.php

**Anyway to solve this?** 
1. Check if request is of type Ajax and comming from your domain

```
if(($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') && ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="http://yourdomain/url")) {
 //Is ajax call
}
```

2.  [Cross-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing); that is denying post from other domains.
3. Generating tokens and validating the token on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anyone can send any data to your insertUser.php

About protection, that depend on use-case. Chceck who is sending data, authorize any request that should be authorized etc.

Best practice is to treat any data from outside (no matter where they came from) as if they were the most dangerous and malicious.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to stop user supplied malicious data inserting into database.

Regarding your situation, you can do the following steps:

1. Check the incoming ajax calls generated from your server.
2. Add [CSRF](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html) through out in your application
3. Always clean inserted data into your database which is called [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), you can read about [SQL injection in OWSAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
4. Always use htmlentities() [Search for htmlentities](http://nyphp.org/PHundamentals/5_Storing-Data-Submitted-Form-Displaying-Database) php function to display output on the screen

Thanks, I hope this will surely help you to understand the security.